# Return word after pattern match in perl

Tags: perl

I have the following perl code:

```
if ($text =~ m{(?<!\ban|\bha)d\s(p[^h])}) { 
    print OUT "${\substr $`, -1, 1} \t ${\substr ($', 0, 1)}\n";
}
```

which finds things like "mad people" in a line of text like "there were mad people there". The next line gives me the context before and after - "a" in "mad" and the first "e" in "people", but I'd also like it to give me the words "mad" and "people." Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can get that easily with the regex you had, but you can get it with a different regex:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

for my $text ('there were mad people there',
              'mathematicians and philosophers',
              'one lad phased out',
              'very old pony',
             ) {

    if ($text =~ m{\b(\w+(?<!an|\bha)d)\s(p[^h]\w+)}) { 
        say join "\n", substr($1, -2, 1),
                       substr($2, 1, 1),
                       $1, $2;
    }
}
```